# (React-Native, Expo) tx.executeSql() is not Working

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, expo-sqlite

```
    useEffect(() => {
        // 테이블 생성
        Chat_DB.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `create table if not exists ${RoomName} (id text primary key not null, date text, sender text, receiver text, peer_key_hash text, server_key_hash text, encrypt_AES_Key text, encrypt_data blob);`,
                null,
                (tx, result) => {
                    console.log('테이블 생성 성공:', result);
                },
                (tx, err) => {
                    console.log('테이블 생성 실패:', err);
                    return false; // 롤백
                }
            );
            console.log("테이블 생성");
        });
        
        
    
        Chat_DB.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `INSERT INTO ${RoomName} (id, date, sender, receiver, peer_key_hash, server_key_hash, encrypt_AES_Key, encrypt_data) VALUES ('1', '0', '2', null, null, null, null, 'Hello!');`,
                null,
                (tx, result) => {
                    console.log('데이터 삽입 성공:', result);
                },
                (tx, err) => {
                    console.log('데이터 삽입 실패:', err);
                    return false; // 롤백
                }
            );
            console.log("초기 데이터 삽입");
        });

        Chat_DB.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(`SELECT * FROM ${RoomName};`, [], (_, { rows }) => {
                console.log('전체 데이터:', rows);
                for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`Row ${i + 1}:`, rows.item(i));
                }
            });
            console.log("초기데이터 출력");
        });

        fetchMessages(); // 함수를 실행합니다.
    }, []); // 컴포넌트가 마운트될 때 한 번만 실행됩니다.
```

In my RN Code, **tx.executeSql** in not working in anyware. but It don't make any log or error.
Just, not working like it that don't existing

I want to run SQLite working in my RN code.
In this code, All of message(Sending, Receiving) is have to saved by SQLite.

> LOG  테이블 생성
> Android Bundling complete 509ms
> LOG  테이블 생성
> › Reloading apps
> Android Bundling complete 218ms
> LOG  테이블 생성
> LOG  테이블 생성
> › Reloading apps
> Android Bundling complete 129ms
> LOG  테이블 생성

Answer (score 0):

Just change the database name `SQLite.openDatabase("main.db")` -> `SQLite.openDatabase("main1.db")`

It works for me.